# CWOP on F1 Visa

Tags: visas, usa, f1-visas

Recently I traveled to India. While traveling back to the USA I got cwop on my F-1 visa in Doha. Then they sent me back to India.

My question is: I have a one year valid OPT (optional practical training). Can I get a new visa for the OPT?

Comment: Why did they do that?  Did they find you inadmissible to the US?  If so on what grounds?  Was it related to the COVID-19 pandemic?

Comment: Was your visa actually still valid according to the validity date on the visa sticker? "CWOP" can also be written on visa stickers by officers to make sure that nobody accidentally considers it to be valid from that point onwards. You may have simply found to be inadmissible because you did not have a valid visa.

Answer (score 5):

CWOP stands for *cancelled without prejudice.*  The phrase *without prejudice* means that the reason for cancellation is not to have a negative impact on your future applications for visas or for admission to the US.

Therefore, you ought to be able to apply for a new visa.  However, I am not sure what the rules are surrounding OPT (for that, you should ask at [Expatriates](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com)), so there may be something going on with that that would prevent it.

The odd thing here, however, is that visas are usually cancelled without prejudice in response to some sort of administrative action.  For example, when one applies for a new visa before the old one is expired, the old visa will be cancelled without prejudice.  A visa cancellation while the bearer is en route to the US would normally be a cancellation *with* prejudice, because the bearer has been found inadmissible for some reason.

On the other hand, if you were prevented from flying to the US because of the travel ban related to COVID-19, I would think that your visa should not have been cancelled at all.

So I wonder whether there is some additional fact that you haven't mentioned that might explain exactly what happened.  If so, that might also have a bearing on the likelihood that a future visa application would succeed.